# Add Test Steps in JUNIT to get better reporting

Tags: junit, jestjs

I am running UI testing with Jest and I am using a custom reporter to generate a JUNIT.xml file at the end of the run https://github.com/jest-community/jest-junit , so that my azure pipeline can read it and generate nice analytics. My test framework is organize around Test suite that represent a big functionality, then each aspect of that functionality is check within a test contain in the suite ( That check might require multiple steps ) and I would like show each of those steps. This way i think it would be more readable for anyone looking at the report and it would be very easy to get context on why a test failed.

- I try to put assertion at each steps. But JUNIT only record the assertion that failed.
- I also try to change the way my test are organize and make a step a test itself. But, in Jest, and it seem in a lot of other runner as well ( at least in Node ) it seem that it's not possible to guarantee easily that test are run in a specific sequence. Also, it's really verbose to code suite like this.

Does anybody have an idea on how I could achieve this granularity ?

Thank you.